# Plot SVM linear model trained by caret package in R

Tags: r, plot, svm, r-caret, kernlab

**Purpose**

I was trying to visualize SVMLinear classification model via `plot`. I am using the example code and data provided in `kernlab` package having noticed `caret` actually train svm via `ksvm` function (referring to src code here (https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/svmLinear.R))

[image]

**Problem**

When I plot the final model of caret model object, it did not yield figure. And I
did not find a way out after I tried three ways.

**Code**

```r
require(caret)
require(kernlab)
# ===== sample codes from ksvm
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(120),ncol =  2), matrix(rnorm(120, mean = 3), ncol = 2))
y <- matrix(c(rep(1, 60), rep(-1, 60)))

# ===== train linear svm model via three wrappers

#===
#dedicated to caret because if I am not preparing data in this way, 
#caret reports errors and stop training with following messages: 
#Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
#At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class 
#probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X.1, X1 . Please use 
#factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).
dat0 <- data.frame(x = x, y= factor(y, levels = c(-1, 1), labels = c('c0', 'c1')))
svp0 <- ksvm(y~., dat0,  type = 'C-svc', kernel = 'vanilladot')

dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = as.factor(y))
svp <- ksvm(y~., dat, type = 'C-svc', kernel = 'vanilladot')

svp1 <- ksvm(x, y, kernel = 'vanilladot', type = 'C-svc')

kernlab::plot(svp0, data = dat0) # works
kernlab::plot(svp, data = dat) # works
kernlab::plot(svp1, data = x) # works

ctr <- trainControl(method='cv',
                    number=5, 
                    classProbs=TRUE,
                    summaryFunction=twoClassSummary 
                    )
svp.c <- train(y ~., dat0, method = "svmLinear",  
               trControl = ctr, 
               preProcess = c('center', 'scale'),
               metric = "ROC")
kernlab::plot(svp.c$finalModel, data = dat0) #Not working
# Error in seq.default(min(sub[, 2]), max(sub[, 2]), length = grid) : 
# 'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

The structure of `svp.c$finalModel` (trained by caret) is same as other `svp` (trained by original `ksvm`), I think. But why `plot` did not works for the former one?

In sum, I was wondering whether someone out there had managed to `plot` SVM trained by `caret` package.

Thank you.

---

Edit2: Attached is my `session.Info()`. Hopefully it helps to identify what I missed.

> R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
>   (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)
>
> locale: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptk4R.png)
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptk4R.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptk4R.png) kernlab_0.9-22  caret_6.0-62    ggplot2_1.0.1   lattice_0.20-33
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptk4R.png) Rcpp_0.12.2
>   magrittr_1.5       splines_3.2.2      MASS_7.3-44        munsell_0.4.2
>
> [6] colorspace_1.2-6   foreach_1.4.3      minqa_1.2.4
>   stringr_1.0.0      car_2.1-0
>
> [11] plyr_1.8.3         tools_3.2.2        parallel_3.2.2
>   nnet_7.3-11        pbkrtest_0.4-2
>
> [16] grid_3.2.2         gtable_0.1.2       nlme_3.1-122
>   mgcv_1.8-7         quantreg_5.19       [21] MatrixModels_0.4-1
>   iterators_1.0.8    lme4_1.1-9         digest_0.6.8       Matrix_1.2-2
>
> [26] nloptr_1.0.4       reshape2_1.4.1     codetools_0.2-14
>   stringi_1.0-1      compiler_3.2.0
>
> [31] pROC_1.8           scales_0.3.0.9000  stats4_3.2.2
>   SparseM_1.7        proto_0.3-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I use `kernlab::plot(svp.c$finalModel)` I get the following output:

[image]

Addendum: results of `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] kernlab_0.9-20  caret_6.0-47    ggplot2_1.0.1   lattice_0.20-33

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6         magrittr_1.5        splines_3.2.2       MASS_7.3-43        
 [5] munsell_0.4.2       colorspace_1.2-6    foreach_1.4.2       minqa_1.2.4        
 [9] car_2.0-25          stringr_1.0.0       plyr_1.8.3          tools_3.2.2        
[13] parallel_3.2.2      pbkrtest_0.4-2      nnet_7.3-10         grid_3.2.2         
[17] gtable_0.1.2        nlme_3.1-121        mgcv_1.8-7          quantreg_5.11      
[21] iterators_1.0.7     gtools_3.5.0        lme4_1.1-8          digest_0.6.8       
[25] Matrix_1.2-2        nloptr_1.0.4        reshape2_1.4.1      codetools_0.2-14   
[29] stringi_0.5-5       compiler_3.2.2      BradleyTerry2_1.0-6 pROC_1.8           
[33] scales_0.2.5        SparseM_1.6         brglm_0.5-9         proto_0.3-10
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind  attaching your session.info?