# Plot SVM trained by caret

Tags: r, plot, svm, r-caret

I am trying to get a plot similar to the one obtained in this post [Plot SVM linear model trained by caret package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095566/plot-svm-linear-model-trained-by-caret-package-in-r)

This code works if I run it on my console, but if I do it with my data it does not work, so I am wondering if it is a problem of my data. Here it is the example that does not work for me:

```
library(wakefield)
X <- r_sample_factor(c("low", "high"), n=232)
MAMAMA<-r_sample_factor(c("C/C", "C/G", "G/G"), n=232)
MEMEME<-r_sample_factor(c("C/C", "C/T", "T/T"), n=232)
MIMIMI<-r_sample_factor(c("A/A", "A/T", "T/T"), n=232)

datos<-data.frame(X,MAMAMA,MEMEME, MIMIMI)

sv<-caret::train(X~., datos, method="svmRadial", trControl= trainControl(method='cv', number=5))

kernlab::plot(sv$finalModel)
```

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: This is the minimal reproducible example. I created a dataset, a model and what I don't know how to continue is with the plot.

Comment: we are missing ```-r_sample_factor```. where is this function from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why the plot works in the link page but not work in your case:
  
 (1) In the link page, `X` only has two predictors, so it can be visualized on a 2-dimensional plane. In your case you have three categorical predictors, and if you dummy them there would be more predictors, I have also searched online but to date I haven't found any solution for `kernlab::plot` to deal with more than 2 predictors. 
 
 (2) In the link page, the code is using `linear` kernel, therefore it's possible to get an explicit expression for the hyperplane, but in your case, you are using `radial` kernel which maps predictors into an infinite feature space, thus hyperplane cannot be expressed explicitly in finite-dimension plot.